# automating the build process for GAE, with uglify, npm, LESS, etc. using Grunt or similar

Tags: google-app-engine, npm, gruntjs

I've a Google Appengine application written in Python. I'm relatively happy with this platform, as well as with the IDE I'm using (JetBrain's PyCharm).

As I'm ready to take my project to the next level, I'm looking for tips and best practice advises for streamlining the "build process", with the following points in mind:

1. Package Manager: My html files are using jQuery, and some other front end libraries. Right now I'm checking in this library with my project. I'd like to get this using some kind of a package manager (e.g. NPM), being able to upgrade and other goodies.
2. LESS processing: I'd like to pre-process my CSS files.
3. Uglify: I'd like to minify/uglify my static javascript files. Optionally, I'd like to uglify my dynamic (jinja2) files as well, if possible.
4. Dev/Production: Locally, I want to use the open version of various libraries (as well as my own files). On production, I want to use the minified version, and fix all references
5. Deploy to GAE: appcfg should be part of the automation as well. However, in the future I may want to deploy somewhere else.

Some files should be available only during development. Some files should be deployed to GAE, potentially after some pre-processing.

I've a little familiarity with Grunt which I believe is the correct task manager for this kind of task, but I'd like to hear solutions based on others (Maven, Ant, Microsoft Build, make, etc.). Please share your wisdom.

Comment: Not really an answer, but could [push-to-deploy](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/push-to-deploy?hl=en) help you?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I don't think so. push-to-deploy will push my entire code base, without any filtering and without any pre-processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't got any experience with using google app engine, but Grunt is really my bread and butter. There's a whole heap of plugins that automate everything that you've listed there and many others. It's quick and easy to set up and if there is a use case that you have which isn't solved by the community already, it's all JavaScript under the hood so you can write your own custom functions. To answer your points:

1. Use [Bower](http://bower.io/) for this. Lots of common front end libraries such as jQuery and Bootstrap have components available, and version management is straightforward too. You won't have to check your components in to version control if you don't want; they are a simple `bower install` away.
2. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less
3. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify
4. This is solved by using Bower for the actual component management and something like https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin to replace the references in the file to minified ones later on in the build step. I've written another answer on usemin so it doesn't need repeating here: [grunt-usemin: Defining custom flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608925/grunt-usemin-defining-custom-flow/19621191#19621191)
5. Again, no experience with `gae` or this plugin so I can't vouch for how good (or not) it is, but here it is anyway: https://github.com/maciejzasada/grunt-gae

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Ben. A key issue is what strategy should I use to filter out filter I don't want on the production site (The GruntFile, and various npm modules, package.json, etc.). Should I somehow build a 'dist' folder, or as I publish my website to host I should do it selectively?

Comment: I'd recommend setting up your `.gitignore` (would hope that you're using version control for this ;-) ) to ignore `node_modules/` and `dist`. Check your `Gruntfile.js` and `package.json` in so that you have the means to build another `dist` copy on another machine. Then presumably everything that `gae` needs is in that dist folder, so you compile that from partials located in other directories.

Comment: .gitignore would work for git.  On app engine use skip_files in your app.yaml.

Comment: What @dragonx said... Between explicit static_files URL mappings, the skip_files directive, and minimizing pollution in your app directory you can do all (or at least almost all) of your pruning without any scripting. Your app directory doesn't have to be where all of your sources live, either. You might put Python in the apps dir, but compile/minify your JS and CSS from outside the app dir and deposit the results inside. I.e., even though your app dir is the root of your deployed app, it shouldn't be the root of your _project_.

Answer (score 3):

There's one important thing to consider that will make this all more complicated: cache-busting.

Let's say you have your own script in custom.js.  You want custom.js to be cached so your web app runs very quickly.  However, when you change your code, you want the new version to be downloaded and used instead of the old cached version.

The common solution for cache-busting is to create a hash value from custom.js and add it to your filename.  So you serve custom.sdf879skdfhsdf9087we.js, and when you update your code, you serve custom.custom.gjf87dskhfhsdfv787we.js.  The same thing applies to your CSS.

Obviously you want to automate this.  And secondly, when you serve your HTML, it needs to know the proper script/css filename to insert into your HTML file.  This is the hard part.

Some python frameworks handle this for you.  For example Django 1.4 does, but I started my app on Django 1.3 and I had to roll my own.  So full process that I wanted, and similar to yours is:

- combine multiple js files into one file
- minify js
- create hash for CSS and update output filename.
- generate python file that has updated output filenames.

My framework then uses the filenames from the generated python file.  I also have a global setting in my framework where I can turn on a "debug" mode that will use the original js files for debug.  There's a similar situation with CSS.

1. I keep libraries outside of my actual GAE project folder and I use a soft-link to it.  appcfg.py will follow the link and upload whatever the link points to.
2. (and 3) I use Apache ant which does dependency checking before actually building.  So instead of building everything every time, it only builds what changed.  I don't know if Grunt does dependency checking, I think it just rebuilds everything.
3. It's best to set up your framework to serve either minified/combined files, or the original files for debugging.  This will involve some custom code.
4. I just wrote a small python script to call ant (which did the first 4 steps) and then call appcfg.py

As an extra tip, you can detect whether you're running on GAE production or the development server:

```
import os

from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub_map

have_appserver = bool(apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetStub('datastore_v3'))
on_production_server = have_appserver and \
    not os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').lower().startswith('devel')
```

I also run my app under two different app ids, one for real production, and one as a test environment on GAE.  I can distinguish between the two using:

```
from google.appengine.api.app_identity import get_application_id
```

And in case you want to use ant, here's a stripped down version of my ant build file.  I'm still using YUI compressor instead of uglify.   It generates a file called script_hashes.py which has all the names of the script files that I later use in my templates.

```
<project name="eat" default="complete" basedir=".">
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
<target name="concatenate" depends="clean" description="Concatenate all files for stove POS">
    <concat destfile="tmp/bootstrap-dropdown-transition-modal-tmp.js">
        <filelist dir="bootstrap/docs/assets/js" files="bootstrap-dropdown.js, bootstrap-transition.js, bootstrap-modal.js"/>
    </concat>
    <concat destfile="tmp/stovepos-tmp.js">
        <filelist dir="stove/scripts" files="pos-combo1.js, pos-combo2.js, pos-combo3.js"/>
        <filelist dir="eat/scripts" files="eat.js, eatorder.js, eatchannel.js, fastbtn.js"/>
        <filelist dir="stove/scripts" files="soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js, stovepos.js"/>
    </concat>
    <concat destfile="tmp/stovehome-tmp.js">
        <fileset file="bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"/>
        <fileset file="eat/scripts/eat.js"/>
        <fileset file="stove/scripts/stovehome.js"/>
    </concat>
</target>
<target name="compress_js" depends="concatenate" description="Compress Javascript">
    <mkdir dir="scripts"/>
    <for param="file">
      <path>
          <fileset dir="tmp" includes="**/*.js"/>
      </path>
      <sequential>
          <apply executable="java" parallel="true">
              <fileset file="@{file}" />
              <arg line="-jar" />
              <arg path="../Downloads/yuicompressor-2.4.7/build/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar" />
              <srcfile />
              <arg line="-o" />
              <mapper type="glob" from="*-tmp.js" to="scripts/*-min.js" />
              <targetfile />
          </apply>
      </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
<target name="compress_css" depends="concatenate" description="Compress CSS">
    <mkdir dir="scripts"/>
    <for param="file">
      <path>
          <fileset dir="tmp" includes="**/*.css"/>
      </path>
      <sequential>
          <apply executable="java" parallel="true">
              <fileset file="@{file}" />
              <arg line="-jar" />
              <arg path="../Downloads/yuicompressor-2.4.7/build/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar" />
              <srcfile />
              <arg line="-o" />
              <mapper type="glob" from="*-tmp.css" to="scripts/*-min.css" />
              <targetfile />
          </apply>
      </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
<target name="clean_tmp" depends="compress_js, compress_css" description="remove all -tmp files">
    <delete dir="tmp"/>
</target>
<target name="complete_js" depends="clean_tmp" description="add checksum to filename">
    <for param="file">
      <path>
          <fileset dir="scripts" includes="**/*.js"/>
      </path>
      <sequential>
        <var name="md5" unset="true"/>
        <checksum file="@{file}" property="md5"/>
        <move todir="scripts">
            <fileset file="@{file}"/>
            <globmapper from="*.js" to="*.${md5}.js"/>
        </move>
        <var name="filename" unset="true"/>
        <propertyregex  input="@{file}" regexp="([^/]*).js$$" select="\1" property="filename"/>
        <var name="filename_" unset="true"/>
        <propertyregex  input="${filename}" regexp="-" replace="_" property="filename_"/>
        <propertyfile file="script_hashes.py">
            <entry key="${filename_}" value="'${md5}'"/>
        </propertyfile>
      </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
<target name="complete_css" depends="clean_tmp" description="add checksum to filename">
    <for param="file">
      <path>
          <fileset dir="scripts" includes="**/*.css"/>
      </path>
      <sequential>
        <var name="md5" unset="true"/>
        <checksum file="@{file}" property="md5"/>
        <move todir="scripts">
            <fileset file="@{file}"/>
            <globmapper from="*.css" to="*.${md5}.css"/>
        </move>
        <var name="filename" unset="true"/>
        <propertyregex  input="@{file}" regexp="([^/]*).css$$" select="\1" property="filename"/>
        <var name="filename_" unset="true"/>
        <propertyregex  input="${filename}" regexp="-" replace="_" property="filename_"/>
        <propertyfile file="script_hashes.py">
            <entry key="${filename_}_css" value="'${md5}'"/>
        </propertyfile>
      </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
<target name="complete" depends="complete_js, complete_css">
</target>
<target name="clean" description="remove all -tmp and -min files">
    <delete dir="tmp"/>
    <delete dir="scripts"/>
    <delete file="script_hashes.py"/>
</target>
</project>
```

Comment: Upvote for pointing out cache-busting, but I have to share my condolences on the whole "using ant" thing... *shudder*